# Why a fault occur when I scheduled a job with my own job scheduler?

Tags: schedulebatch, scheduled-job

I wrote a scheduler code for batch job and made it a package. 
Then, I installed it to a few ORGs and it works good on them.
But, when I installed another ORG and run it, a error occur as following:

```
Scheduler: failed to execute scheduled job: jobId: 707m0000003cgFB, class:
common.apex.async.AsyncApexJobObject,
reason: Illegal assignment from void to MAP<Id,SET<Id>>
```

I think I already excluded all issues from code, so could this error message from ORG`s setup?
||||-_-

Comment: I suggest nevertheless you post some code as presumably somewhere you are using `MAP<Id,SET<Id>>` and seeing the code may help someone answer.

Comment: Is it possible you are seeing differences either due to data in the specific Org or triggers or affected objects.

Answer (score 1):

I found the crux of this question. In my code, I normally put up to 5 batch classes into a schedule job, and  then server system will complie them (batch classes). Here is the essensial point that a batch class thereof can not be compiled, because a method be called in that class had been changed and not longer return a value... :-(